# Asp.Net 2.0 File upload

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I know I use the asp FileUpload control for uploading a file but I need to change the design of the control to an image button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it your referring to the style of the 'Browse...' button. Its styling cannot be modified very easily as its appearance is set by the browser. Here's a workaround involving  HTML, CSS and JavaScript:

Article: [Styling an input type="file"](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)